# HTML & PHP: Wrong button allignment and wrong output

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this comment system made with PHP and JS (dialogify) and I have two problems: one is obviously the buttons' allignment and the second is the output of the dialog. At the end of each line i get a `<br>` even though the line ends without going actually on a new line and the row won't update after pressing ok, I have to reload the page to actually see the updated content.

[image]

EDIT: Now the buttons are alligned

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
            <form method="post" action="">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" value="Edit" type="button" onclick="edit_row('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>');" /><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" name="delete_reply" type="submit"><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></button>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

Here is the code I use to display the comments.

```
        $query_reply = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE postID=?");
        $query_reply = $mysqli->bind_param("i",$postid);
        $query_reply ->execute();
        $row = $query_reply->fetch_assoc();
        <div id="content_val<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo nl2br($row['reply']);?><br /></div>
```

The code for the insertion

```
if (isset($_POST['edit_row'])) {
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE replies SET reply=?  WHERE id=? AND postID=?");
$id = $_POST['id'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$postid = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql->bind_param("sii", $content, $id, $postid);
if ($sql->execute()) {
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE postID='$id'");
    $sql->bind_param("i", $postid);
    $sql->execute();
}
}
```

EDIT 2: I managed to make the content update in real time by changing the action after `$sql->execute();`

```
if ($sql->execute()) {
    print "success";
} else {
    $error_message = "Problem in editing Record";
}
```

Comment: first issue, is probably form has by default css of full width, so one btn is before form and the other in form, which makes them look like this.

Comment: The thing is that obviously if I add the first button inside the form after I press the button itself my page will just refresh. Is there any way I could change the css to make them fit?

EDIT: First problem solved, I added type="button". I didn't think of that.

Comment: nl2br this function does this, it inserts break tags at the end of each line, and you are  also inserting a <br> at the end

Comment: why would it refresh it? its not a submit type, make it a button type,and you have a js event on it, it should not reload page or do anything to the form

Comment: I removed the nl2br but still the same, every time I remove the <br> tags they just keep appearing

Comment: try ctrl+f5 multiple times to cache clean, and make sure there is no br in insert code.

Comment: I cleaned the caches, tried on incognito too but still the same problem and also deleted every <br>.